# How to Change the Selected Item Background Color in the Opened DropdownMenu in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How to change the selected item background color in the opened DropdownMenu? I want to change the selected item background color in the opened DropdownMenu.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can change color by adding MenuStyle

```
DropdownMenu(
  menuStyle: MenuStyle(
    backgroundColor:  MaterialStateProperty.all( Colors.grey),
  ),
),
```